# How do I make use of FsCheck custom generators from C#?

Tags: fscheck

I have the following code:

```
var gen = from x in Arb.Generate<int>()
from int y in Gen.Choose(5, 10)
where x > 5
select new tuple { Fst = x, Snd = y };
```

And I can run

```
Prop.ForAll<tuple>(c =>
      Console.WriteLine($"{c.Fst}, {c.Snd}")
).Check(Configuration.Default);
```

I see all the ways to construct generators and define properties.

But I just don't find quickly enough how to use them together.

Answer (score 6):

You need to register the custom generator with FsCheck. See  [FSCheck docs](https://fscheck.github.io/FsCheck/TestData.html#Default-Generators-and-Shrinkers-based-on-type).

In short, create a class to keep your custom generators. Have a public static method returning an `Arbitrary<T>` where `T` is the type you are generating.

In your example, you would need to wrap your generator in a call to `Arb.From(...)`.

```
public class MyGenerators {
    public static Arbitrary<tuple> Tuple() {
        return Arb.From(from x in Arb.Generate<int>()
                        from int y in Gen.Choose(5, 10)
                        where x > 5
                        select new tuple { Fst = x, Snd = y });
    }
}
```

Finally, call `Arb.Register<MyGenerators>()` before running your test.